# Trouble with .grid() in python 3 with buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

So i'm trying to position 2 buttons on my tkinter GUI, but it seems that setting the row and column aren't working as they should. If i set the grid row/column  to a value the button will move over a bit, then if i try to set the button grid again, it won't move anymore. Wondering if the way i created the button is affecting the grid function? All in all im just trying to position my buttons, and I can't seem to get them to move.

```
#Play button creation
btnPlay = Button(app, text ="Play", command = playMusic)
btnPlay.grid(row =10, column = 10)


#Pause button creation
btnPause = Button(app)
btnPause.grid()
btnPause.configure(text = "Stop", command = stopMusic)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `grid` without specifying a `row` and a `column`. I'm also not sure what "it" is in "it'll move over" and "it won't move." Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems you did not understand how `grid` really works. I recommend you to have a look at the effbot page on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Rows and columns have a size of zero if they don't contain anything. Putting something in column 10, when there is nothing in columns 0-9 is the same as putting it in column 0.